# Passing argument to python script within a batch file in Windows

Tags: python, batch-file

I have a python script that can be called in Windows as:

```
python.exe do_my_work.py param > output.csv
```

param is an input parameter.

I also have a txt file called params.txt that contains many lines, each line is a value for the parameter of the python script:

```
hello
world
this
is
test
```

Because params.txt consists of many many lines, so I would like to write a .batch file that read params.txt line by line then calls python script with the read line as the parameter. The pseudo code as:

```
open params.txt;
while !eof do:
    read a line;
    call "python.exe do_my_work.py $line >> output.csv";
end while;
close params.txt;
```

Could you please show me how to solve this.

P/S: I don't want to change do_my_work.py source code due to some special reasons.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
@echo off

set "params=C:\params.txt"
set "output=output.csv"

for /f "usebackq tokens=* delims=" %%# in ("%params%") do (

   python do_my_work.py %%# 1>>"%output%"

)
```